# How to draw a native checkmark without the QCheckBox box

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to draw a check mark in Qt that looks like the native check marks used in `QCheckBox`es. I'd like to be able to also draw the partially checked state like in a `QCheckBox`. Summarized: I'd like to draw the contents of a `QCheckBox`, but without the box. I'm working in Qt 4.8.

I tried drawing the primitive element for a check mark with these calls:

```
// Draws nothing (or nothing that I can see).
QStyleOption styleOption;
styleOption.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
styleOption.state |= QStyle::State_On;
QApplication::style()->drawPrimitive( QStyle::PE_IndicatorItemViewItemCheck, &styleOption, &painter );

// Also draws nothing.
QApplication::style()->drawPrimitive( QStyle::PE_IndicatorViewItemCheck, &styleOption, &painter );
```

When I use the following calls, I do see the drawing, but there is a complete `QCheckBox`, with the 'box' around it that I don't want.

```
// Draws the complete QCheckBox.
QStyleOptionButton styleOptionButton;
styleOptionButton.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
styleOptionButton.state |= QStyle::State_On;
QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_CheckBox, &styleOptionButton, &painter );

// Also draws the complete QCheckBox.
QStyleOptionButton styleOptionButton2;
QCheckBox dummy;
styleOptionButton2.initFrom( &dummy );
QApplication::style()->drawPrimitive( QStyle::PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &styleOptionButton2, inPainter );

// Also draws the complete QCheckBox.
QStyleOption styleOption;
styleOption.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
styleOption.state |= QStyle::State_On;
styleOption.rect = QRect( 0, 0, 16, 16 );
QApplication::style()->drawPrimitive( QStyle::PE_IndicatorItemViewItemCheck, &styleOption, &painter );
```

When I use the following call to draw other primitive elements, they do get drawn, but are not the check marks used in `QCheckBox`es (and they are plain ugly).

```
// Draws an ugly check mark.
QStyleOption styleOption;
styleOption.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
QApplication::style()->drawPrimitive( QStyle::PE_IndicatorMenuCheckMark, &styleOption, &painter );
```

So is there a way to draw only the check mark of a `QCheckBox` without the box?

Comment: What style options do you pass? That's important. You need to look at the source code for the style you're using and see what options are expected by the primitive drawing implementations. I'd at least expect to see a proper `rect` and `state`.

Comment: @KubaOber: The `state` contained the `QStyle::State_Enabled` flag and one of `State_On`, `State_Off` or `State_NoChange` flags. I indeed did not initialize the `rect`. When setting a real `QRect` as `rect`, I do see something with the first two `drawPrimitive` calls, but they paint the complete `QCheckBox` and not only the check mark.

Comment: Dig into the style code. Most likely the platform only provides an image for the entire control, and not just the checkmark. OTOH, depending on the platform, the checkmark may just be a glyph from some font. What platform is that, what exact style?

Comment: try debugging inside the Qt code to understand how this part of the code works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone else doing something like this it's as simple as setting the style sheet on a `QCheckBox's` indicator.

Set its stylesheet with a line like this:

```cpp
QCheckBox box;
box.setStyleSheet(QString("QCheckBox::indicator{ border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }"));
```

Doing so will set the border indicator to become transparent. You could also overwrite the checked/ hovered stylesheet attributes to be a custom checkmark or any custom icon you please. Combining these effects can lead to a very modern looking front end.